# Advantages of formal unit testing over just writing a lot of examples?

Tags: r, unit-testing

R has three well-developed unit testing packages, `RUnit`, `svUnit`, and `testthat`.  Base R has examples built into its package functionality, which will return an error if they do not parse properly.

The opinion of those whom I trust is that unit testing is better than writing lots of examples, but I can't quite put my finger on any specific functionality in unit tests that can't be replicated in examples.

What features of using a unit testing framework in R make it superior to the *ad hoc* equivalent using package examples?

For those not from the R world, note that examples for every function in a package are run each time the package is built, and the programmer is made to suffer for any warnings or errors.

Comment: Testing whether a function parses correctly *may* test that you have no syntax errors, but may not catch symantic errors. A unit test could, for example, test that a function returns an object of the correct class. How do you replicate that with an example?  Do you check the example results yourself?

Comment: It's worth noting here that one can also test whether graphical output has changed during development by using Winston Chang's `vtest` package: https://github.com/wch/ggplot2/wiki/Visual-test-system

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a unit test framework you can test all kinds of things that you may not want to expose as examples to the end user:

- Does the function throw the correct error with incorrect input? A unit test framework will catch the error, thus passing the test.
- Unit testing should aim to get really high coverage of the code. You may want to test all of the combinations of all of the input arguments.

Another advantage of unit test frameworks is speed:

- You can selectively run tests in a given file, for example. In contrast, depending on package output means you need to build and check the entire package.
- This leads to much quicker identification of errors and a quicker development cycle.

My typical packages would contain dozens, if not hundreds of tests, but only a few examples that really demonstrate what the package is about.

In summary, I use tests to test, and examples to educate and help.

Comment: +1 First answer so far that has actually addressed the specifics of the question.  Is it fair to say then that examples can replicate a most of the unit testing functionality (by things like `stopifnot(class(x)=="character")` ) but that since they're intended for end-users they are not the appropriate place to do so?

Comment: Unit test are just much more flexible than just using R examples, e.g. The output of a function should always be positive. A downside of unit testing in general is that for complex systems the number of tests grows exponentially.

Answer (score 3):

It of course depends which kind of examples you have, but most probably the examples are not showing how not to use the code. Unit tests can also test behaviour in negative cases.

Unit tests probably test smaller parts and therefore simpler functionalities. Tests that use frameworks can be typically run automatically after each code change. If you rely on someone running the examples all the time, sooner or later they are forgotten in some critical moment.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph.  The second does not jive with R's examples system, which get run every time the package is built.

Comment: @Ari, I think your comment above is a crucial point and maybe it should be added to your question. Because examples are run as part of the build process, they do act as unit tests in a sense. So your question is more about what differences are left and what would be appropriate content for each.

Answer (score 2):

One of the obvious difference between *tests* and *examples*, is that tests can be a part of the development cycle. In test-driven development **TDD** each new feature begins with writing a test.

I will no detail here the TDD concept ( I hate generality and I think the topic is well developed in the literature) But If you always finish a session of coding
by creating a failing test for the feature
you want to implement next, it will be easier for you to pick
up where you left off when you want to continue your development.

Answer (score 1):

Running unit tests are normally fully automated so much cheaper (less developer time) to run than manual testing. Of course it takes time to write them but normally less time than would be spent later on manual testing.

If development is done in the team, it is usually also good to have automated builds on the server to make sure that all new code does not break anything. This is also more possible if the tests run without any interactions with the real human.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of unit testing is that one single red or green answer comes out. You need not examine the results to see if everything is still working as expected.

Comment: Using examples in a package also does not require you to manually examine the output, checking the R package will run the test and report if there where any error, and if the output changed.

Comment: Does it glare at you in red which ones failed and show happy green colors for the ones that succeed?